# Configure nginx to rewrite hashes on all paths

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I use nginx as a static file server first and try to rewrite all uri if they contain hashes to point to a mock directory.

It might be more clear with an example

let's say the user request pages url like theses :

```
/api/some/path/to/ecbac7cb-21ca-3d22-98ed-4d063f138d0b/some/other/path/02167621-5c01-45c5-98ba-eb3ba1bf4b2a/list

/api/some/other/path/to/ecbac7cb-21ca-3d22-98ed-4d063f138d0b
```

I want to try to get the file at first but the fallback would be somthing like this

```
/api/some/path/to/__any_hash__/some/other/path/__any_hash__/list.json

/api/some/other/path/to/__any_hash__.json
```

here is a config I tried to far... but obviously, it's not working.

```
server {
 ...
 location /api {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri.json $uri.xml @rewrites;
 }

 location @rewrites {
  rewrite /([0-9\-a-f]{36})/ __any_hash__ break;
  try_files $uri.xml $uri.json @backend;
 }
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `location @rewrites` should probably look like this:

```
location @rewrites {
    rewrite "^(.*)/[0-9\-a-f]{36}(/.*)$" $1/__any_hash__$2 last;
    return 404;
}
```

The `$1` and `$2` capture the URI fragment before and after the hash to be substituted. The `last` causes the `location /api` to be reattempted after the substitution. The process will loop until all of the substitutions are made. The `return 404` is only invoked if the fully substituted URI fails to find a file.

Comment: Why limiting to `{10}` in length the hash, is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: @zeachco Oops yes - in my testing I couldn't be bothered to type 36 characters. Updated answer.